# Difficulties displaying tapestry grid component. (Apache Tapestry 5 framework)

Tags: java, frameworks, tapestry

I want to display in a **t:grid** component a List of items, but i don't know why i get a **NP**

I am sure 100% that the List i am retuning is not empty.
This is the java part of the page that calls the method that accesses the data:

```
public class MyTelephones {

    @Property
    @SessionState
    private User user;

        @Property
    @Persist
    private Telephone telephone;

    @Property
    @Inject
    private UserDataAccess userDataAccess;

    public List<Telephone> showTelephones() {
        return userDataAccess.getUsersTelephones(user.getName());
    }
```

This is the page with the markup that should display them:

```
<html xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_1_0.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Show your telephones</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>These are your telephones [${user.name}]</h1>
        <t:grid source="${showTelephones()}" row="${telephone}"/>

        <h3><t:pagelink t:page="Index">Go back!</t:pagelink></h3>   

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the error i get?

```
[ERROR] pages.MyTelephones Render queue error in BeginRender[MyTelephones:grid.rows]: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid.rows: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid.rows: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException [at classpath:org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.tml, line 8]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:194)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$BeginRenderPhase.render(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:246)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:72)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderQueueImpl.render(PageRenderQueueImpl.java:127)
    at $PageRenderQueue_1309430978d.render($PageRenderQueue_1309430978d.java)
    at $PageRenderQueue_13094309785.render($PageRenderQueue_13094309785.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MarkupRendererTerminator.renderMarkup(MarkupRendererTerminator.java:37)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$29.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2089)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$28.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2073)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$27.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2055)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$26.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2040)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$25.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2026)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$24.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2008)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$23.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1989)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978c.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978c.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageMarkupRendererImpl.renderPageMarkup(PageMarkupRendererImpl.java:47)
    at $PageMarkupRenderer_1309430978a.renderPageMarkup($PageMarkupRenderer_1309430978a.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageResponseRendererImpl.renderPageResponse(PageResponseRendererImpl.java:67)
    at $PageResponseRenderer_130943096d0.renderPageResponse($PageResponseRenderer_130943096d0.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderRequestHandlerImpl.handle(PageRenderRequestHandlerImpl.java:64)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$36.handle(TapestryModule.java:2326)
    at $PageRenderRequestHandler_130943096d2.handle($PageRenderRequestHandler_130943096d2.java)
    at $PageRenderRequestHandler_130943096cc.handle($PageRenderRequestHandler_130943096cc.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handlePageRender(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:48)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handlePageRender(InitializeActivePageName.java:47)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_130943096cd.handlePageRender($ComponentRequestHandler_130943096cd.java)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_130943096b1.handlePageRender($ComponentRequestHandler_130943096b1.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderDispatcher.dispatch(PageRenderDispatcher.java:45)
    at $Dispatcher_130943096b3.dispatch($Dispatcher_130943096b3.java)
    at $Dispatcher_130943096ae.dispatch($Dispatcher_130943096ae.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:321)
    at com.mirsad.services.AppModule$1.service(AppModule.java:96)
    at $RequestFilter_130943096ad.service($RequestFilter_130943096ad.java)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$4.service(TapestryModule.java:984)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:974)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:85)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:103)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096a4.service($RequestHandler_130943096a4.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:272)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_130943096a3.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_130943096a3.java)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:928)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.java)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a1.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a1.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1148)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:387)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:865)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:539)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid.rows: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException [at classpath:org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.tml, line 8]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.writeToBinding(ParameterWorker.java:350)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.set(ParameterWorker.java:296)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows._$set_row(GridRows.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows.setupForRow(GridRows.java:283)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows.beginRender(GridRows.java:304)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows$MethodAccess_beginRender_13094309850.invoke(GridRows$MethodAccess_beginRender_13094309850.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.RenderPhaseMethodWorker$Invoker.invoke(RenderPhaseMethodWorker.java:117)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.RenderPhaseMethodWorker$RenderPhaseMethodAdvice.advise(RenderPhaseMethodWorker.java:86)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.java:86)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows.beginRender(GridRows.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$BeginRenderPhase.invokeComponent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:176)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException [at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Grid.rows]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.bindings.PropBinding.set(PropBinding.java:76)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.writeToBinding(ParameterWorker.java:346)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException [at classpath:com/mirsad/pages/MyTelephones.tml, line 7]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.writeToBinding(ParameterWorker.java:350)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.set(ParameterWorker.java:296)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Grid._$set_row(Grid.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Grid.setRow(Grid.java:577)
    at $PropertyConduit_13094309896.set($PropertyConduit_13094309896.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.bindings.PropBinding.set(PropBinding.java:72)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.bindings.AbstractBinding.getBindingType(AbstractBinding.java:63)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.writeToBinding(ParameterWorker.java:344)
    ... 98 more
[INFO] AppModule.TimingFilter Request time: 141 ms
[ERROR] TapestryModule.RequestExceptionHandler Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: Render queue error in BeginRender[MyTelephones:grid.rows]: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid.rows: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueException: Render queue error in BeginRender[MyTelephones:grid.rows]: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid.rows: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException [at classpath:org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.tml, line 8]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:84)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderQueueImpl.render(PageRenderQueueImpl.java:127)
    at $PageRenderQueue_1309430978d.render($PageRenderQueue_1309430978d.java)
    at $PageRenderQueue_13094309785.render($PageRenderQueue_13094309785.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MarkupRendererTerminator.renderMarkup(MarkupRendererTerminator.java:37)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$29.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2089)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$28.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2073)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$27.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2055)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$26.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2040)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$25.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2026)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$24.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:2008)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$23.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1989)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978f.java)
    at $MarkupRenderer_1309430978c.renderMarkup($MarkupRenderer_1309430978c.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageMarkupRendererImpl.renderPageMarkup(PageMarkupRendererImpl.java:47)
    at $PageMarkupRenderer_1309430978a.renderPageMarkup($PageMarkupRenderer_1309430978a.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageResponseRendererImpl.renderPageResponse(PageResponseRendererImpl.java:67)
    at $PageResponseRenderer_130943096d0.renderPageResponse($PageResponseRenderer_130943096d0.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderRequestHandlerImpl.handle(PageRenderRequestHandlerImpl.java:64)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$36.handle(TapestryModule.java:2326)
    at $PageRenderRequestHandler_130943096d2.handle($PageRenderRequestHandler_130943096d2.java)
    at $PageRenderRequestHandler_130943096cc.handle($PageRenderRequestHandler_130943096cc.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handlePageRender(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:48)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handlePageRender(InitializeActivePageName.java:47)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_130943096cd.handlePageRender($ComponentRequestHandler_130943096cd.java)
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_130943096b1.handlePageRender($ComponentRequestHandler_130943096b1.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderDispatcher.dispatch(PageRenderDispatcher.java:45)
    at $Dispatcher_130943096b3.dispatch($Dispatcher_130943096b3.java)
    at $Dispatcher_130943096ae.dispatch($Dispatcher_130943096ae.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:321)
    at com.mirsad.services.AppModule$1.service(AppModule.java:96)
    at $RequestFilter_130943096ad.service($RequestFilter_130943096ad.java)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$4.service(TapestryModule.java:984)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:974)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:90)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:85)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:103)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096af.service($RequestHandler_130943096af.java)
    at $RequestHandler_130943096a4.service($RequestHandler_130943096a4.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:272)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:53)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_130943096a3.service($HttpServletRequestFilter_130943096a3.java)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:928)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a6.java)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a1.service($HttpServletRequestHandler_130943096a1.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:147)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1148)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:387)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:417)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:535)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:865)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:539)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
    at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:520)
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid.rows: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException [at classpath:org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.tml, line 8]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:194)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$BeginRenderPhase.render(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:246)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:72)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid.rows: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException [at classpath:org/apache/tapestry5/corelib/components/Grid.tml, line 8]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.writeToBinding(ParameterWorker.java:350)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.set(ParameterWorker.java:296)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows._$set_row(GridRows.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows.setupForRow(GridRows.java:283)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows.beginRender(GridRows.java:304)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows$MethodAccess_beginRender_13094309850.invoke(GridRows$MethodAccess_beginRender_13094309850.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.RenderPhaseMethodWorker$Invoker.invoke(RenderPhaseMethodWorker.java:117)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.RenderPhaseMethodWorker$RenderPhaseMethodAdvice.advise(RenderPhaseMethodWorker.java:86)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractComponentMethodInvocation.java:86)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.GridRows.beginRender(GridRows.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$BeginRenderPhase.invokeComponent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:239)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:176)
    ... 81 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException [at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Grid.rows]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.bindings.PropBinding.set(PropBinding.java:76)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.writeToBinding(ParameterWorker.java:346)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.TapestryException: Failure writing parameter 'row' of component MyTelephones:grid: java.lang.NullPointerException [at classpath:com/mirsad/pages/MyTelephones.tml, line 7]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.writeToBinding(ParameterWorker.java:350)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.set(ParameterWorker.java:296)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Grid._$set_row(Grid.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Grid.setRow(Grid.java:577)
    at $PropertyConduit_13094309896.set($PropertyConduit_13094309896.java)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.bindings.PropBinding.set(PropBinding.java:72)
    ... 93 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.bindings.AbstractBinding.getBindingType(AbstractBinding.java:63)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ParameterWorker$2$1.writeToBinding(ParameterWorker.java:344)
    ... 98 more
127.0
```

What is wrong, am i calling correctly the method showTelephones()?

Is there any other alternative how i couldPass the parameter user.name to the method getUsersTelephones(), but from within the markup page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your notation. Your template should be:

```
<t:grid source="showTelephones" row="telephone"/>
```

and your java should be:

```
public class MyTelephones {

    @Property
    @SessionState
    private User user;

    @Property
    private Telephone telephone;

    @Property
    @Inject
    private UserDataAccess userDataAccess;

    public List<Telephone> getShowTelephones() {
        return userDataAccess.getUsersTelephones(user.getName());
    }
```

Since the grid is in the tapestry namespace you do not need to use the ${}. I am a bit confused why Tapestry doesn't complain about your notation and throws an NPE but I'm pretty sure this will fix it for you.

PS: @Persist'ing your row value is not a good idea as it will only persist the latest row in your table.

Comment: Yes it works. So i don't allways need to use the baces { }. Is the reason of that that i use the @Property anotation? If i used get and set methods instead would i need to say ${telephone}  ?

Comment: no the property literally is the same as getters and setters. It has to do with if the property you are setting in your .tml file relates to a parameter in the component or if it is a dom/html property. eg <t:grid source="propertySourceFromYourJavaFile" class="${propertyStringFromYourJavaFile}"/>. Here source is bound to the source parameter in the Grid component and since class is just html it needs to use the expressionlanguage if you wish to retreive its value from the java file. I hope that makes sense.

Have a look at: http://tapestry.apache.org/property-expressions.html

Comment: I fully understand now where my mistake was :) Thank you very much!

Comment: The ${...} notation is primarily for use outside of Tapestry components. It explicity converts the value referenced to a String, and acts as a read only property.  So your List<Telephone> was converted to a String and that caused problems inside the Grid component.